# How to return an error message to the browser when condition fails in java?

Tags: java

I am sending just an message when condition fails.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String downloadFormDataAsPdf(
@PathVariable("id") String id){
    if(!id.isEmpty())
    {
       // code
    }
    else{
       return "You are not allowed"
    }
}
```

I am writing this under requestMapping GET method in  the controller..But what i am getting is only a some part of error message is displayed in the browser.CAn i know why .I need to get full text message if condition fails.

Comment: You can't just return a `String` to the browser! You need to return HTML. You need a **template** and you need to have a **placeholder**. You populate the placeholder with your messages and then **render** the a **full and valid** HTML page. If you're just getting started with web development, then maybe use something like JSP as a view engine for a servlet. If you are already using Spring MVC, for example, then there are plenty of templating engines supported, for example Thymeleaf.

Comment: I have updated the question.Once see it again and help me to solve

Comment: This formatting is unbearable. Please format your code according to convention...